# Как задать родительский пакет в пайтон

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули, импорт

Привет я пытаюсь выполнить относительное импортирование модуля всё делаю как в книжке но получаю ошибку`:attempted relative import with no known parent package` 
Если родительский пакет не известен то как его сделать известным [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
_`"Aurel-папка в которой хранятся два модуля
     akavir.py - основной файл в котором я хочу выполнить импорт
     timer.py - файл который я хочу импортировать 
     __init__.py"`
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, текст, не снимки экрана.

Comment: @MarianD извините исправил

Comment: большую черную картинку тоже исправьте

Comment: @eri всм? вы имеете ввиду скрин?

Comment: давать имя `timer.py` модулю -  не очень хорошая идея.

Answer (score 0):

В python-3 относительные импорты работают по-другому. В Вашем случае сработает

```
import timer
```

Comment: Спасибо получается что Лутц меня обманул

Comment: У него версия другая, во втором импорт относительно каталога, в третьем относительно пакета. Но к пакету требования другие